# Database column encryption in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, encryption-symmetric

in my database i used database column encryption using symmetric key. I followed this tutorial  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/ . it uses symmetric key and it is not visible to others. But a database admin can see the encrypted column by executing query that calling symmetric key.

```
USE EncryptTest
GO
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DECRYPTBYKEY(EncryptSecondCol)) AS DecryptSecondCol
FROM TestTable
GO
```

I need a encryption in database level and database admin also should not able decrypt the column. is it possible in database level encryption?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a DBA who is a member of the sysadmin role on that instance to have any access to the keys, then you cannot allow the database to do the encryption.

Even if you try using the PASSWORD option of [CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188357.aspx), the DBA can use Profiler to see the password inside of the SQL statements.  The DBA certainly has access to the Master Key (and may already have a backup of it).

You will need to have your application do the encryption if you want to hide data from DBA's.

Or you can trust your DBA's with the data they're protecting.

Comment: But as long as both keys & certificates are there in same database server, anyone who gets access to the server can always decrypt the data. Then where is the security?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked, SQL Server 2016 has been released and the Enterprise Edition contains a feature called Always Encrypted, which is design with a certificate in a client driver encrypting a column encryption key on the server that performs the encryption. I would recommend putting the "client" on a middleware server like IIS for websites and web services where the certificate can be better protected.

A second solution to encryption beyond the reach of the DBA is to introduce an Extensible Key Management system. Support for this is also an Enterprise only feature. An Extensible Key Management system is a separate expansion board or system interfaced with SQL Server to offload all key management and encryption processing that can be put under the administration of a different team than the DBA.

Third, you can design a solution which includes dropping the private key of the certificate and having it in a location that is not accessible to the DBA. When the private key is dropped from a certificate in an encryption hierarchy, then the data can only be encrypted.